# How do I safely (i.e. crash resistantly) serialize docs in spacy?

Tags: serialization, spacy

I have a pretty big corpus of texts that I use to make a few million Doc-objects.

I am somewhat familiar with the usage of DocBin(), but it looks like it loads all the Docs to memory before dumping it to file. Seems a bit risky and crash-prone. Ideally I want to be able to continue where it stopped should a crash or unexpected exit occur.

I came up with two options:

1. Write every doc as a single file with Doc.to_disk.
2. After the first x iterations I write the docbin to file, then every x iteration after that I load the docbin-file, merge it with the ones in memory, then write that new DocBin to file again.

Anything I've missed here? What are the up- and downsides to these methods? Any other suggestions?